# How to sort processes in java?

Tags: java, sorting

I am having issues with sorting processes in my program. Here the code I have
`Collections.sort(cpu, Comparator.comparing(cpu.arrivalTime));`
This is sorting the arrival time in the process cpu. When I run the program the error I am getting is: error: no suitable method found for comparing(int).

What do I need to change in order for this to work?

I am trying to implement a class for FSFS cpu scheduling and for everything else to work, I need to sort the arrival times of the process.

Comment: How are you getting the cpu information.  `cpu` looks like it might be a class reference. `Collections.sort `takes a `collection` and an `optional comparator` as arguments.

Comment: The cpu information is in a separate excel file that is being read in. In a different class I have this line: while (inputStream.hasNext()) {
   Process process = new Process(inputStream.nextInt(), inputStream.nextInt(), inputStream.nextInt());
   csvFile.add(process);
  }

Comment: what is the exact data you are tryng to sort on.  For example, do you have a `List<Process>` where each  Process has the three ints.  If so, which one is the cpu (do you have getters?)  The Process class would be useful.

Comment: 1) Is the variable `cpu` an array? 
2) For me it is strange the second parameter usage. It should be a function. You can check this examples: https://www.infoworld.com/article/3323403/java-challengers-5-sorting-with-comparable-and-comparator-in-java.html 
3) Is the CPU class implements Comparable ?

Comment: The other option is to just let `Excel` sort the CPU information.

Comment: That's not valid syntax. Perhaps `Comparator.comparing(cpu -> cpu.arrivalTime)` is what you're looking for. And note your error is a **compilation** error, not a run-time error.

Answer (score 0):

Without more information, we can only guess.  Assuming that you have a `List<Process>` where each `Process instance` contains `three ints`. You could do it like this.  Here, a record is used as the Process class.

```
record Process(int getCpu, int getSomethingElse1, int getSemeThingElse2) {}
List<Process> processes = new ArrayList<>(); // populated with Process info
Collections.sort(processes, Comparator.comparingInt(Process::getCpu));
```